Confluence Kafka Producer and consumer client Unit Tests
.NET 6
Confluent.kafka v1.9.3
I have created a Confluent Kafka Consumer client application to receive messages from topic which is working as expected.
Now I am trying to create Nunit test project for testing the Consumer application. I tried out creating and using Moq objects and results for the build method of ConsumerBuild, consume method of consumer. But I am not able to see the Mock object injected in test setup as the result of build and consume methods.
I found some MockProducer and MockConsumer classes available for Java. But couldn’t found any mock classes for .NET.
How to test out Producer and Consumer client applications using .Net 6.
